# Center the images in label thumbnails

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a specific template that worked really well until someday the images on the thumbnails in the main page got messed up. I don't even know what happened and I am unable to fix it.

It looks like the image thumbnails are showing only the left upper side and when I used

```
img.label_thumb {
    width: 100%
}
```

in the CSS and it looks great now, but the carousel, that goes with the same image stared looking awful.
I tried changing the way the carousel looks in the HTML but I couldn't.

The web is recapblog.com and I am starting to get really desperate here guys, I tried everything I know and I could find on the internet (even thought is not much).
How it is supposed to look in the thumbnails and carousel

[image]

How it looks with the CSS

[image]

I found something I didn't try before, but I'm afraid to touch something and mess it all up!
This is it:

// jCarouselLite plugin
(function($){$.fn.jCarouselLite=function(o){o=$.extend({btnPrev:null,btnNext:null,btnGo:null,mouseWheel:false,auto:null,speed:200,easing:null,vertical:false,circular:true,visible:3,start:0,scroll:1,beforeStart:null,afterEnd:null},o||{});return this.each(function(){var b=false,animCss=o.vertical?"top":"left",sizeCss=o.vertical?"height":"width";var c=$(this),ul=$("ul",c),tLi=$("li",ul),tl=tLi.size(),v=o.visible;if(o.circular){ul.prepend(tLi.slice(tl-v-1+1).clone()).append(tLi.slice(0,v).clone());o.start+=v}var f=$("li",ul),itemLength=f.size(),curr=o.start;c.css("visibility","visible");f.css({overflow:"hidden",float:o.vertical?"none":"left"});ul.css({margin:"0",padding:"0",position:"relative","list-style-type":"none","z-index":"1"});c.css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative","z-index":"2",left:"0px"});var g=o.vertical?height(f):width(f);var h=g*itemLength;var j=g*v;f.css({width:f.width(),height:f.height()});ul.css(sizeCss,h+"px").css(animCss,-(curr*g));c.css(sizeCss,j+"px");if(o.btnPrev)$(o.btnPrev).click(function(){return go(curr-o.scroll)});if(o.btnNext)$(o.btnNext).click(function(){return go(curr+o.scroll)});if(o.btnGo)$.each(o.btnGo,function(i,a){$(a).click(function(){return go(o.circular?o.visible+i:i)})});if(o.mouseWheel&&c.mousewheel)c.mousewheel(function(e,d){return d>0?go(curr-o.scroll):go(curr+o.scroll)});if(o.auto)setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll)},o.auto+o.speed);function vis(){return f.slice(curr).slice(0,v)};function go(a){if(!b){if(o.beforeStart)o.beforeStart.call(this,vis());if(o.circular){if(a<=o.start-v-1){ul.css(animCss,-((itemLength-(v*2))*g)+"px");curr=a==o.start-v-1?itemLength-(v*2)-1:itemLength-(v*2)-o.scroll}else if(a>=itemLength-v+1){ul.css(animCss,-((v)*g)+"px");curr=a==itemLength-v+1?v+1:v+o.scroll}else curr=a}else{if(a<0||a>itemLength-v)return;else curr=a}b=true;ul.animate(animCss=="left"?{left:-(curr*g)}:{top:-(curr*g)},o.speed,o.easing,function(){if(o.afterEnd)o.afterEnd.call(this,vis());b=false});if(!o.circular){$(o.btnPrev+","+o.btnNext).removeClass("disabled");$((curr-o.scroll<0&&o.btnPrev)||(curr+o.scroll>itemLength-v&&o.btnNext)||[]).addClass("disabled")}}return false}})};function css(a,b){return parseInt($.css(a[0],b))||0};function width(a){return a[0].offsetWidth+css(a,'marginLeft')+css(a,'marginRight')};function height(a){return a[0].offsetHeight+css(a,'marginTop')+css(a,'marginBottom')}})(jQuery);
$(function() {
    $(".cover").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        auto: 4000,
        speed: 800
    });
});

Comment: Can you post your blogger's web url?

Comment: The web is www.recapblog.com

Comment: Everything looks fine here on Chrome.

Comment: Once in a while it looks good for some reason and when you refresh it goes back to awful, I'm going crazy with this template

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to fix. Your title and description are both confusing. Center an image in a thumbnail? Please clarify and simplify.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not very used to this and english is not my mother language. 
I would like the center the image in the thumbnail and I tried with the CSS I wrote before and worked, but then the carousel that goes with the same image has the pictures only half way in the cage.

Comment: Quick try this `img.label_thumb {
    width: 395px; height: auto;
}`

Comment: I think it looks the same?

Comment: What about using the image as a `background-image` and then using `background-size:cover` on your container (skipping the `img` element)?

Comment: But then I would have to upload the picture not only in te post but in some other place right?

Answer (score 0):

ok so you have to remove this :

```
.img.label_thumb {
    width: 100%;
}
```

remove `width 100%` from this rule and it should work properly

but if you wanna keep this rule you must add `height : 100%` to fit the image to the carousel height

Comment: But then it would look like the images in the thumbnails are moved to the left and uper side of the thumbnails space

Comment: yeah but the images are different size you can't make the carousel change it's size with every image !!

Comment: But I have a trial website for the same page (http://probandocositasrecap.blogspot.fr/) where it all works perfectly, how everything worked at the beggining and I tried to find the difference between the two webs and I can't

Comment: I doesn't look the same to me, the images in the carousel and in the thumbnails look centered and normal in the second page but in www.recapblog.com the appear only in half of the carousel, not centered

Comment: or you will find css class called .cover try to decrease the max-height to 248px , this is not the best solution in the word but it works

Comment: .img.label_thumb in this class try to add height : 100%

Comment: Oooh that worked! I looks a little bit odd but it's better I think!

Comment: if this helps you don't forget to market as the answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use `background-size:cover;` and `background-image:url(...)` on your `.imageContainer`.

So change the rules in `#coverflow .recent-box .imageContainer` to this

```
background-size:cover;
width: 395px;
height: 450px;
```

And then for each `.imageContainer` in your carousel, remove your `img` tag and add `style="background-image:url('url-to-image')"`.

```
<div class="imageContainer" style="background-image:url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-HhpzYfbtE9g/VPXVy5roMKI/AAAAAAAAAhg/h27Yk_7LXv4/s1600/ouat.PNG');">
    ...
</div>
```

Then the image will fill the whole div while containing the aspect ratio.

[image]

Comment: But I don't upload the photos manually, where do I find the .imageContainer?